# JOOQ Does Not Respect Default Value Inside the generated POJO's

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm trying to create a new schema with a new column with a default value not null.
Somehow in the generated DAO, I can see that JOOQ doesn't respect and delegate the default value.
Would you happen to have any idea how to fix this?
The generated code looks like this:

```
@Override
public ReleaseBundleVersionRecord setInternal(Short value) {
    set(20, value);
    return this;
}
```

But I expected to see something like:

```
@Override
public ReleaseBundleVersionRecord setInternal(Short value) {
    if(value == null){
         set(1, (short) "anyDefaultValue");
     }else{
         set(1, value);    
     }
   return this;
}
```

Please your help...

I expected to get a genearted POJO including my NONNULL default value 0;
So the genearated POJO should includes the below code:

```
@Override
public ReleaseBundleVersionRecord setInternal(Short value) {
    if(value == null){
         set(1, (short) "anyDefaultValue");
     }else{
         set(1, value);    
     }
   return this;
}
```

Comment: I've answered your *specific* question. You probably have an underlying use-case that leads to your expectations, and it might be useful for you and future readers to discuss that as well, in a separate question. E.g. there's probably a reason why you want this default in your POJO, but there might be other ways to achieve what you *actually* want to achieve, so maybe, having the default in the POJO isn't the best way in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some sort of SQL `DEFAULT` expression on your `CREATE TABLE` statement, such as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE release_bundle_version (
  ..
  internal smallint DEFAULT 0,
  ..
);
```

And now you're expecting jOOQ's code generator to take this `DEFAULT` expression and also generate it in various places of generated code.

This has been requested a few times but it isn't practically possible. While your specific `DEFAULT` value is a constant that *could* be translated to Java code, there is nothing keeping you from using a runtime evaluated expression, e.g. `DEFAULT y + z` (deterministic) or `DEFAULT current_timestamp` (non-deterministic), which would be hard to evaluate in the client.

As such, what you're expecting isn't possible, and probably won't be in the future, either.